# MYSQL Statement for Missed Appointments in the Last 30 Days

Tags: mysql, join, view, insert

I have seen a few posts similar to this question. I have tried adapting each one to fit my needs, but I have come up short. Hopefully someone can provide some assistance with this mysql statement:

Parent Table: Client

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Child Table: Appointment

```
CREATE TABLE `appointment` (
  `aptID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` enum('Assessment','Follow-up') DEFAULT NULL,
  `outcome` enum('Show','No Show') DEFAULT NULL,
  `last30` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aptID`),
  KEY `fk_appointment_client1_idx` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_appointment_client1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `client` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need a report of the following:

1) number of appointments in the last 30 days
2) number of appointments in the 365 days
3) number of appointments ever
4) number of missed appointments in the last 30 days

I created a view that gives me everything except for the last one (missed appointments), but I couldn't figure out how to incorporate the missed appointments:

```
CREATE VIEW `total`
AS SELECT
   id AS id,
   name AS name,
    count(`C1`) AS `Last30days`,
    count(.`C2`) AS `Last365Days`,
    count(`C3`)  AS `Alltime`

FROM (select
client.id AS id,
client.name AS name,
(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) <= 30 THEN NULL end) AS `C1`,
(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) <= 365 THEN NULL end) AS `C2`,
(select count(*) from appointment where id=client.id) as `C3`

from 
(client left join appointment on((client.id = appointment.id))))
group by `total`.`id`;
```

**Question 1**: How can I incorporate missed appointments in the last 30 days into this view? Missed appointments would be operationalized as appointments in the last 30 days where the outcome variable was 'No Show'. I thought it would be by adding these two lines:

```
count(`C4`) AS `Missed30`

(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) <= 365 where outcome = 'No Show' THEN NULL end)  AS `C4`
```

**Question 2**: 
How do I turn the whole statement into an insert statement to periodically capture data from the view. This would be going into a table called apt_total. I have tried a few variations but nothing has come close to working.

Thanks, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use SUM(IF()) and SUM a 1 if the condition matches. See below.

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) <= 30, 1, 0)) AS Last30Days,
  SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) <= 365, 1, 0)) AS Last365Days,
  COUNT(*) AS AllTime,
  SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) <= 30 AND outcome = 'No Show', 1, 0)) AS NoShow
 FROM
  appointments AS a
  INNER JOIN clients AS c ON a.id = c.id
 GROUP BY
  id
```

This should give you the numbers you're looking for.
If you want to turn the SELECT into an INSERT, you would do the following.

```
INSERT INTO apt_total
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) <= 30, 1, 0)) AS Last30Days,
  SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) <= 365, 1, 0)) AS Last365Days,
  COUNT(*) AS AllTime,
  SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) <= 30 AND outcome = 'No Show', 1, 0)) AS NoShow
 FROM
  appointments AS a
  INNER JOIN clients AS c ON a.id = c.id
 GROUP BY
  id
```

You will need to make sure the columns are the same, otherwise you change the INSERT INTO apt_total into the following:

```
INSERT INTO apt_total (col1, col2, col3.....)
```